# How to pass a nested array in ReactTable getTrProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-bootstrap, react-table

I have a nested array for customers indicating whether they have paid for services offered. Am using ReactTable to display the data. I would like if customers have paid, the row with the customer that has paid to be highlighed in Yellow. Currently am getting the TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status').

How can i improve the code below in order to correct the error status is undefined. Thanks in advance

Json Output

```
  [{
  "customers": {
      "_id": "63e9303a16267390f9304321",
      "customerdetails": "63e6a4d21aeb535a4fe1b841",
      "status": "Paid",
      "amountPaid": "500",
      "roomNo": "2",
      "servedby": "Wade Jones",
      "createdAt": "2023-02-12T18:30:18.756Z",
      "updatedAt": "2023-02-12T18:30:18.756Z",
      "__v": 0
   }
  }]


ReactTable code  

<ReactTable

  getTrProps = {(state, rowInfo, instance) => {
        if (rowInfo) {
          return {
            style: {
              background: rowInfo
                ? rowInfo.row.customers.status === 'Paid'
                  ? "Yellow"
                  : "none"
                : "none"
            }
          };
        }
        return {};
      }}

  />
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to access the 'status' property of an undefined object. You need to check if the 'customers' object is defined before attempting to access the 'status' property.

*Change the code to the following:*

```
    <ReactTable

  getTrProps = {(state, rowInfo, instance) => {
        if (rowInfo && rowInfo.row.customers) {
          return {
            style: {
              background: rowInfo.row.customers.status === 'Paid' ? "Yellow" : "none"
            }
          };
        }
        return {};
      }}

  />
```

Comment: Thanks @Oyinkansola Shoroye for the response. The error undefined object has been solved. However, the expected background color change for each row with status Paid does not function.

Comment: The issue may be with the way the 'getTrProps' function is being called. I will edit my answer now.